# How to release memory when using JetUpdate to insert record in Extensible Storage Engine Database?

Tags: memory-leaks, extensible-storage-engine

I need to insert millions of records.Right now I'm in a very tight loop where, for every record, I

```
a) start a transaction  (JetBeginTransaction)
b) prepare an update (JetPrepareUpdate)
c) add the row (JetSetColumns)
d) update (JetUpdate)
e) commit the transaction (JetCommitTransaction)
```

But more and more memory is occupied, when records are inserted by excuting *JetUpdate*. Even if I stop to excute insert records or all records are inserted, the memory would not be released.

How could I limit the memory to rise?

Why the *JetCommitTransaction*  does not release the memory?

How to release the memory timely?

Comment: Anyone can help me ?

Comment: So, why are you doing a single insert per transaction?   As for memory leaks, do you have something like:  <code>            finally
            {
                // close down
                Api.JetCloseTable(sesId, tableId);
                Api.JetCloseDatabase(sesId, dbId, CloseDatabaseGrbit.None);
                Api.JetDetachDatabase(sesId, databasePath);
                Api.JetEndSession(sesId, EndSessionGrbit.None);
                Api.JetTerm(instance);
            }</code>

Answer (score 0):

The database cache is likely growing. Confirm with the Perf Counter: `Database -> Database Cache Size (MB)`.

You can cap the size with `JET_paramCacheSizeMax` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/extensible-storage-engine/database-cache-parameters ).

I also agree with egray's comment that you should insert more than one insert per transaction. Or at least use Lazy Commit (a flag to `JetCommmitTransaction`). Otherwise you will be writing to your transaction log file much too frequently, and perf will greatly suffer.